# What changes are needed to my django app when deploying to pythonanywhere? error points to nowhere

Tags: django, wsgi, pythonanywhere

Deploying my django website with S3 as storage which runs fine locally to pythonanywhere gives a strange error I can't google a solution for:

"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

What I'm doing wrong?

I've tried to put my environment variables out of settings.env (aws keys, secret_key, etc) ad set them directly in my settings.py app. + every suggestion I could find but it's still the same :(

here's my /var/www/username_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py:

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own Django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

from dotenv import load_dotenv

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/portfolio_pa/WEB')  # adjust as appropriate
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, 'settings.env'))

# assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
path = '/home/corebots/portfolio_pa'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'WEB.settings'

## Uncomment the lines below depending on your Django version
###### then, for Django >=1.5:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
###### or, for older Django <=1.4
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I'd expect the website to run fine just like it does locally.

Comment: the full error: https://pastebin.com/DqUie4Pp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boto library doesn't have a good Python3 support. This particular issue is known in the boto bugtracker: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3837

The best way of fixing this is to use [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) which has decent Python3 support and is a generally most supported AWS SDK for Python.

The reason why it works on your local machine and doesn't work on production is that pythonanywhere setup seems to be using proxy which triggers this incompatible boto code. See the actual calling code: https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/connection.py#L747

Your error traceback confirms this.

Unfortunately, I'm not familliar with the `django-photologue`, but a brief look doesn't suggest that it strongly depends on boto3. Maybe I'm wrong.

I still think that the best way is to go with boto3. As a backup strat you can fork boto with a fix for this issue and install that instead of the official one from PyPI: https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3699

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible that when I run the website locally storage on S3 seems to work fine? It's only now when  I try to to deploy it on PythonAnywhere when it throws this error and keeps me from starting the server. 

Also, if I read correctly, boto isn't compatible with boto3. I'm using django-photologue to store all images and static on S3 - will I need to rebuild the catalogue with boto3?

Comment: Updated an answer. Hopefully it clarifies things

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it. Since it's a lot of photos in categories and tags, I'm first going to try your other suggestion, but I first need to do some research on how to install a forked version of boto.